# Magento2 : how can I call my theme images

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, image, media-images

I am trying to convert some M1.9 emails to M2 and it currently calls the images from

```
<img src="{{skin url="images/logo_email.gif" _area='frontend'}}
```

I've tried

```
<img src="{{view url="images/logo_email.gif"}}
```

I have all the images in app/design/frontend/Vender/Theme/web/images. Is this the correct location?

It works if I pull from the media folder with `<img src="{{media url="/wysiwyg/logo_email.gif"}}`, but I would really like to know how to pull from the theme folder in M2. I think it's a permissions issue as I cannot pull up any image from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Here are a few things to try:

First of all, you're missing the `design/` folder in your location path. Move the files to `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/images.

Next, try adding the theme name to as an argument to the view directive: `{{view theme="yourtheme" url="images/logo_email.gif"}}`

Also, make sure that you run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Sorry left that out of the file path but it is in the design folder. Thank you.